# Details in summary on one line?

Tags: css, html

I want my details inside footers appear in a row, now displayed each on a new line. How can I make it work with CSS?

```
<footer>
        <P>Kontakta mig på följande sätt</P>
        <details>
            <summary>Mail</summary>
            <p>Bla bla bla</p>
        </details>

        <details>
            <summary>Telefon</summary>
            <p>Bla bla bla</p>
        </details>

        <details>
            <summary>Brev</summary>
            <p>Bla bla bla</p>
        </details>           
</footer>
```

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `<detail>` tag is block element so you can set for it width in percent, height in pixels and style `float:left` . Otherwise just wrap `<details>` in another floating `<div>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` to make it happen that way.

```
footer details {
  display: inline;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y8tb5jnt/

Comment: Great! Thanks you man! This is my first projekt ever so I´m  a little bit novis! Haha

Comment: This not work in Chrome 87

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline;`

should do the trick for that

```css
footer p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <P>Kontakta mig på följande sätt</P>
        <details>
            <summary>Mail</summary>
            <p>Bla bla bla</p>
        </details>

        <details>
            <summary>Telefon</summary>
            <p>Bla bla bla</p>
        </details>

        <details>
            <summary>Brev</summary>
            <p>Bla bla bla</p>
        </details>           
</footer>
```

Comment: What do you mean with p after footer?

Comment: This targets all the `<p>` elements _specifically_ within the `footer`, which means if you have other `<p>` elements on the page, this doesn't affect their styling

Comment: Ok i understand but i want all the details element be affected. In your suggestion is only the paragraph that be affected right?

Comment: the `<p>` element automatically starts a new line, so it's only this element that causes the line break. If you run the above snippet, you'll see that it works.
You can also apply it to `footer details` to apply the styling to anything that sits in any of the `<details>` tags

Comment: Aha thanks man! But it doesn't work? All three summary elements displayed on new rows not the same row.

Comment: This not work in Chrome 87. Neither *{display:inline}