# Show/hide text in a html only page

Tags: html, show-hide

This problem has plagued me for years. In a HTML only page how do you *properly* create a inline "show more text" / "show less text" button. HTML only environments pop in places like editing wikis or markdown files.

the `<details>` tag is almost what I want. Except it adds two additional unwanted newlines.

```
<p>
 I want this text on the same line
  <details>
   <summary>as this text</summary>
  and this text</details>
</p>
```

If there was a "negative newline" character I could delete the extra newlines the `<details>` tag adds but I don't think such a thing exists.

[This link](https://jsfiddle.net/y8tb5jnt/) from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877833/details-in-summary-on-one-line#answer-39877867) shows how to use `display: inline-block` to remove one of the two newlines. However it requires using CSS.

[This link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_read_more) shows how to make a show more show less button. But it requires you make unique ID's for each button, which is just not feasible for large pages. Also there are some wikis which don't allow you to use functions.

I could make the "main text" be the `<details>`'s `<summary>` text. But in environments like in bulleted lists it will create the bullet, a new line, the main text, a new line, the .

It seems frustratingly simple that there doesn't seem to be an HTML only answer to this.

Comment: What's the problem in using CSS?

Comment: For example, the internal facing wiki that the company Amazon uses to document all their internal knowledge doesn't support CSS. Also markdown editors let you add chunks of HTML code, but don't let you add CSS content.

Comment: You'll only ever be able to do what controls are made and allowed for you. However this exercise is very good for you because you'll come out with a deep understanding. Markdown editors are designed to be extremely simple. You seem to want a semi-complicated markdown editor.

Comment: Why do you need inline collapsible text? Why not use a **table of contents** and sections to jump to? What is the problem with **footnotes** to link to? Why don't you **parenthesize** additional text instead of hiding it? Should you want to go into more detail, maybe you need a separate section/page?

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not an context, environment, or a programmation language. It's a protocol to structurate information in a TCP (HTTP) comunication.

In a very very specific way, HTTP is the protocol indeed and HTML is the markup language or "content" to structurate the protocol, but is not a programming language.

I could do this analogy:

Voice: HTTP
English: HTML
Writing: CSS

CSS is part of HTML as fundamental protocol to design the representation of that document. There is not such thing as "hide" in a protocol, there is such thing as "hide" in the representation of that document, so that's the main reason that is on CSS and not HTML.

So no, the condition if someone can read or not read is on the `writing`, not in `English`

Comment: The OP explained the context quite a bit. I think on a high-level "HTML-only environment" makes complete sense. Does it help if you change the word "environment" to "context"?

Comment: Yes, and I will update to be more specific, but I think the answer is still "no, there is no way"

Comment: If you can use javascript document.getElementsByTagName("details").  does not use an id , you require to obtain the correct [index] it brings back as an array of that element.   HTML is a graphical formatter for documents for use with an html rendering user agent app, comprising a DTD Document Type Definition that of an HTML DOM Document Object Model of it's allowed tag elements  Of recent in XHTML , DOM has been refined to "Schema" added to XML DOM.

Comment: Javascript requires an interpreter of the script. We can still discuss if javascript is a language as is not compilated, but requires an interpreter. So for HTML is still a "no" as in any communication protocol: if you want to hide it: don't say it. Another example is IRC protocol, you can hide it with the client, but if you can read the communication, you can read the private message.

Comment: Changed "environment" to "page" to avoid confusion. I'm referring to HTML as a programming language and not as a communication protocol. And the purposed of doing this is to make a document pretty and easy to read, not for information security.

Comment: @ChristopherPratt HTML is not a programming language, is only the "protocol" of the communication. The document has their own rules, everything about it you can learn it at https://www.w3schools.com/ but it still a "no" for your question because is not the reason of HTML. That's why exists CSS. In any case, style="" is a HTML definition.